# Production server not recognizing Symfony folder path

Tags: deployment, symfony1, symfony-1.4, production-environment

Just delpoyed my symfony website to the production server and I am getting this issue:
Anyone wonder what's up ?

require_once(/home/vsource4/www/students/lib/vendor/symfony-1.4.14/symfony-1.4.14/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoLoad.class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /home/vsource4/www/students/sfproject/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 4

This is not the case, because my symfony installation does exist here:
/home/vsource4/www/students/lib/vendor/symfony-1.4.14/symfony-1.4.14/

Now what can be a good reason herE?

```
    <?php

require_once('/home/vsource4/www/students/lib/vendor/symfony-1.4.14/symfony-1.4.14/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php');

sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');
    $this->setWebDir('/home/vsource4/www/students/sfprojects/web');
 //   $this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/web');
  }
}
```

I have used absolute paths, the paths are correct.
thanks

Comment: What about folder permissions for the www-data user?

Comment: Can your post your ProjectConfiguration.class.php  ?

Comment: If you get stuck you can always drag a copy of your symfony installation into project/lib and project/data - it's easier in production to have a project self-contained anyway.

Comment: Hi Halfer, this is exactly what I have done...put the symfony/lib and symfony/data/ directories into project/lib and project/data

Answer (score 0):

Tried clearing the symfony cache?

Comment: yes, ofcourse actually I resolved the problem by redoing things on the server (bad), this time it worked, the last time it did not, wonder what's up